# Updating Feed according to privacy settings (PostgreSQL, Redis) using fan-out write approach

Tags: database, postgresql, redis, feed

I am planning a system design for a social network, with 'following' relationships between users (like Instagram) and posts that they can post.

If user A follows user B, user A can see all the content of B on their timeline, irrespective of whether B also follows A. 
But, if B decides to set his privacy setting to Private, user A shouldn't be able to see the content of user B anymore.

I wanted to use the fan-out write approach (push method) for the user Feeds/Timelines , that is : Storing in Redis the most recent posts of all the people they're following. So when Users A, B and C all follow User D, and user D posts a new post, I update the feed list of users A, B, and C. It helps fetching the feed in O(1) for each of them, which is nice.

But, what if user D sets his privacy settings to "private", and he only follows user B. It means that only user B should now be able to see his content. So I need to remove the content of user D from the lists of user A and C in redis.

But isn't that too unreliable? if we have many users with many followers, can we get an edge case where users can still see content they shouldn't be seeing for some time until Redis finishes updating their feed lists?

Also, it means that I should also store in redis the information if the users follow each other or only one follows the other.

How is it implemented in the "real world" (twitter,facebook, instagram ....) , am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer:

That is completely reliable because the redis operations are atomic, if you use it correctly no user will be able to see content that was hidden by privacy settings.

A longer answer:

**It is not scalable**:
If your network grow in the future, this is not going to work, redis is single threaded, redis will store everything in memory.

**It is not space efficient**: If you think in a graph, you are suggesting to store a list of the content on the edges instead of the nodes. Let's say that on average a person has `f` followers, your approach will store `f` times more data, for a typical social network it could be 100s of times more.

**It penalises writing speed**: You are trying to speedup the access by avoiding reading from all followers. Now when someone is posting content you will have to write `f` copies of it on average. If this locks some tables that may delay everything.

**This could be done efficiently isomg the DB**: If you have a table connections with primary key (u1, u2) indicating that u1 follows u2. A table user_privacy with columns (u, p) with a primary key on u indicating that u have the privacy settings one

You can get the user following me that I don't follow by

```sql
select t1.u2 from connections e1 -- I follow
  -- e2 Follows me back
  left join connections e2 on e2.u1 = e1.u2 and e2.u2 = e1.u1
  inner join user_privacy up on up.u = e1.u2
where e1.u2 = (myself) and (e2.u1 is NULL or up.p) 
-- e2.u1 is null if user does not follows me back
```

From this list of users if you have a table posts with (post_id, user, date) and an index (user, date) you can easily get posts for date in an interval.
Then you keep changing interval until you load enough posts and when you scroll.

About your concern related to time I think it is OK, if the content was once available for user A, it can still see it for several reasons. e.g. It didn't reload the feed, cache, or he could even have made a copy of the content.